# How to select n number of random integers within a specific summary

Tags: postgresql

I need to get list of random integer like below...

```
select FunctionNeeded(min_num, max_num, row count, sum of rows);
```

What I want to get as the result is

```
select FunctionNeeded(1, 10, 5, 30);
-----------------------------------------
5
6
7
10
2
```

Is there any function or something?

Any of altanative way would be also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What parameters would you want to pass to the function? Range? Length? Etc?

Comment: FunctionNeeded(min_num, max_num, the number of row, sum of rows). I edited the question. I'm sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. I didn't understand what the 30 is for though:

```
create function FunctionNeeded(
  value_from int, value_to int,
  number_of_values int, something_else int) returns setof int as $$
select floor(random() * (1+$2-$1))::int + $1
from generate_series(1,$3)
$$ language sql;
```